# Investigate Fibonacci sequence

Tags: calculus

The Fibonacci sequence is defined by $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$

a) Show that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} ≤2$

b) Let $f(x)=∑_{n=1}^∞a_n x^{n-1} $ show that this series converges for x<1/2. Where is the convergence uniform?

c) Show that $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2+x-1}$ for $x<1/2$

d)Use the partial fraction decomposition of $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2+x-1}$ to get another series expansion of $f$

e) Use the two power series representation of the same function to show 
$a_n=\frac{(\frac{1+√5}{2}  )^n-(\frac{1-√5}{2}  )^n}{√5}$

here is what I got so far

a)
Proof:
We will prove $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} ≤2$ using proof by induction

Base case: $\frac {a_2}{a_1} =1<2$

Inductive step: Assume that $k∈N$ and $k≥3$  such that $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} ≤2$. Show that $\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_{k+1}} ≤2$.

Note that 
$\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_{k+1}} =\frac{a_{k+1}+k_n}{a_{k+1}} =1+\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}} $

Since $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} ≤2$, $\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k+1}}≥1/2$

Bu this doesn't take me anywhere.

b)
Proof : 
Assume that $f(x)=∑_{n=1}^∞a_n x^{n-1} $. Show that $f(x)$ converges for $x<1/2$.
Since $a_n>0$, using ratio test, we obtain
$D_n=\frac{a_{n+1} x^n}{a_n x^{n-1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}  x≤2x <1 $    if $x<1/2$

So we have shown that $f(x)$ converges for $x<1/2$.

Let $x≤x_0$, then
$|a_n x^{n-1} |≤|a_n x_0^{n-1} |$

Similarly, use the ratio test we have ∑_{n=1}^∞ a_n x_0^{n-1}  converges for $x_0<1/2$. 
By the M-test, $f(x)$ converges uniformly on $(-∞,x_0)$ for $x_0<1/2$.

for c),d), and e). I'm not sure I know how to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** for part a):  Prove the *stronger* assertion

$$1\le {a_{n+1}\over a_n}\le2$$

Comment: from what I got, I already shown that $\frac {a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}} \geq 1$, but how to show it less than or equal 2

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif, ${a_{n+1}\over a_n}\ge1$ is equivalent to ${a_n\over a_{n+1}}\le1$.  Make use of this in the line of your proof that says "Note that...."